# Visualization of Graph Algorithms to teach about Dijkstra's, Prim's, etc?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to help undergrads visualize some basic graph algorithms, like Prim's and Dijkstra's. This [audible representation of sorting algorithms](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8g-iYGHpEA) got a great reaction. I'm looking around for something similar for graphs, but haven't been able to find anything yet.

It would also be cool if I could find some app that would let me specify a graph, then watch the algorithm progress step by step.

(The specific algorithms themselves aren't terribly important; anything that works on graphs would be sufficient for our purposes. Even breadth first or depth first search.)

**Know of any good graph algorithm visualizations/interactive apps?**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://www.algoanim.info/Animal2/), it's called **Animal** and it's a software written in Java exactly for the purpose you need.

Inside the repository you should be able to find almost every algorithm needed, with animations and explainations provided. In any case you can also extend it by writing your own visualization..

Comment: Hey @PeterBecich the site seems to be down. Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Data Structure Visualizations](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Algorithms.html).

(See also http://visualgo.net.)